# What Azure services to use for a new phone developer?

Tags: azure, windows-phone

I have been developing Windows Phone Apps for a while now, since WP7 first came out. I have written countless apps, but never actually released any that use an external service.

I am finally getting ready to release one of my first apps that requires a service, and have decided to go with Azure as my host.

Now for the question:
For this specific App, I need an offering that will allow me to host a very small amount of images and text, not even in the hundreds at this time. From what I have looked up, it seems like a database would be the preferred method of storing such a small amount of data, however, thinking into the future, would it be better for me to get the smallest table or blob storage (200gb) and use that? I will most likely be writing other apps that will most likely also require services, however, it is hard to tell what kind of services I would need. I could require a database rather than a blob if I am not storing images... or I may require a blob if I am, again, storing images...

If anyone has been in this situation before, which would you recommend, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store images in blobs and other information in Table Services or Sql Database.

Which one to choose? It will vary according to your requirement.

See

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2012/07/26/windows-azure-storage-sql-database-versus-table-storage.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj553018.aspx